# How to show that $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3\geq abc+abd+acd+bcd$ if $a,b,c,d>0$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, roots

How can I prove that if $a,b,c,d>0$ then

$$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3\geq abc+abd+acd+bcd?$$

I think there is some simple proof but I can't remember...
is this a special case of some general inequality?

---

I need it to prove that if $a^3+2c=3ab$ then all of 4 positive roots of following polynomial is the same.

$x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

Comment: Mathematical formulae look better in $\LaTeX$. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) is a quick tutorial.

Comment: Are you sure the LHS is correct?

Comment: I think LHS should be $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3$...

Comment: If what's up there is correct, then the LHS simplifies down to $3a^3+b^3$, which means I could easily choose $c,d$ so that this inequality is false.

Comment: I assumed that BBB was correct about the LHS and edited accordingly; if that is wrong, you can fix it. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for explanations of the markup I used.

Comment: You can also use rearrangement inequality, this is a special case.  How is it related to the quartic though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**hint**: Use AM-GM inequality $4$ times:

$$x^3+y^3+z^3 \geq 3xyz$$

with $(x,y,z) = (a,b,c), (a,c,d), (a,b,d), (b,c,d)$, and add up.

Comment: OH MY MY... TNX